# Excluding a PHP Interface from PHPUnit code coverage

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I've got a PHPUnit test that tests a class called HelpTokenizerTest. This class implements TokenizerInterface. For some weird reason I cannot exclude the TokenizerInterface from code coverage.

It shows up in code coverage reports as not covered, despite using @codeCoverageIgnore or even @codeCoverageIgnoreStart/End.

Any ideas?

I don't want the interface included in my test coverage, as it doesn't do anything. What's the point of testing an Interface.

Comment: are you using a configuration xml or a test suite ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a phpunit.xml you can set up filters to exclude files with particular names, in particular folders or with an particular extension.

see [the documentation for it](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.whitelisting-files)

**Example:**

```
<testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
    <directory>./application/</directory>
</testsuite>

<filter>
    <blacklist>
        HERE
    </blacklist>
       or alternatively
    <whitelist>
        <directory suffix=".php">../library/</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">../application/</directory>
        <exclude>
            AND HERE
            <directory suffix=".phtml">../application/</directory>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

Comment: Note that PHPUnit will ignore the blacklist if you define a whitelist, so you must use the `<exclude>` block in a whitelist as shown above.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks Samuel & David!

Answer (score 2):

You can use *@codeCoverageIgnore* as a comment at the beginning of the file to get 100% 0/0 coverage.

```
<?php // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart 
interface MyInterface
{
    public function myfunction();
}
```

Note that it doesn't work in a comment block.

Issue open on PHPUnit's github: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/497